# Grouping Nested Lists Based on Differing Values of Single Element

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, formatting, filtering

I've a list of lists representing k-rows of truth table having n elements each in a nested list
consider

```
 lst={{True, True, True}, {True, True, False}, {True, False, True}, {True, 
    False, False}, {False, True, True}, {False, True, False}, {False, 
    False, True}, {False, False, False}}
```

i want to get all those sublists having n-1 elements same but differ by jth element

e.g. if i want the 2nd element to of a given list to be different i should get the following result group:

```
 lst={{{True, True, True},  {True, False, True}}, {{True, True, False}, {True, 
 False, False}}, {{False, True, True}, {False, 
 False, True}},{{False, True, False}, {False, False, False}}}
```

similarly, if i want the third element to be differnt i should get this:

```
lst={{{True, True, True}, {True, True, False}}, {{True, False, True}, {True, 
  False, False}}, {{False, True, True}, {False, True, False}}, {{False, 
  False, True}, {False, False, False}}}
```

I'll be thankful for anyone helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example data:

```
Module[{l = #, ll = Length@#[[1]], ta, s},
   ta = ConstantArray[True, ll];
   ta[[#2]] = False;
   s = Subsets[l, {2}];
   s[[Flatten@Position[SameQ @@@ Transpose@# & /@ s, ta]]]] &[lst, 2]

(*
{{{True, True, True}, {True, False, True}}, {{True, True, 
   False}, {True, False, False}}, {{False, True, True}, {False, False,
    True}}, {{False, True, False}, {False, False, False}}}
*)
```

Probably much faster, certainly more concise:

```
With[{l = #, c = Complement[Range@Length@#[[1]], {#2}]},
     Cases[GatherBy[l, #[[c]] &], {_, __}]] &[lst, dp]
```

In either, first argument is your list, second argument is the element position in sublists you wish to differ.